# TestNG running on different threads when using timeout, Is there a possibility we can use same thread

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

I am trying to create a threadLocal webdriver.

Trying to initialize and login into over application in @BeforeClass.

@test is having functionality. This test is working properly but whenever i use @test(timeOut=1200) it is getting failed due to timeOut's in Testng  run on a different thread.

But whenever there is a timeOut in the @test(timeOut=1200) TestNG is creating Two new thread for the @beforeclass and @test.

Is there a possibility that it will run in a single thread.

I have tried TestNG-7.0.0-beta1 with -Dtestng.thread.affinity=true JVM agrument.
But it stills fails to fulfill my requirement.

Thanks,
balraj

Comment: Can you  try this `@Test(timeOut=1000) // specify time in milliseconds`

Comment: sorry manoj that is not what i required anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest released version of TestNG viz., `7.0.0-beta1`, this is currently not supported within TestNG. Whenever you specify a `timeout` attribute for an `@Test` method, TestNG spawns it in a separate thread so that it can enforce timeouts.

But this behavior is applicable only for the `@Test` method and not for

- the listeners (either the `IInvokedMethodListener` provided `beforeInvocation()` (or) `afterInvocation()`) (or)
- for the configuration methods such as `@BeforeMethod` (or) `@AfterMethod` annotated configurations

[ These are the only set of methods which TestNG usually runs on the same thread as the `@Test` method ].

This issue as you are also aware is being tracked via https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/914